# Multiple Definitions of _Unwind_Resume

Tags: c++, linker, mingw

For a while, I've been using a small collection of files I wrote making it easier to interface with WinAPI. Although, it's become a pain to keep moving the files around when I want to reuse them, waiting for them to recompile, etc. I finally decided to just throw them in a DLL, and be done with it, but I'm getting an odd link error every time I try to use the library.

The error is really as specific as the title, providing little information about where the definition actually originates(considering, that kind of information can't really be collected from a DLL, as far as I'm aware). Could someone please explain exactly what would cause this error, as well as providing some possible fixes to the problem?

I'm using MinGW(the same version provided by the SFML site, 4.4) along with Code::Blocks, if that information helps any. If any more information is required, I'll do my best to provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there are multiple definitions for a symbol (function or variable) named `_Unwind_Resume`.

The DLL is exporting such a name.  Rebuild it so that it only exposes desired symbols.  Apparently, it is now built with all public symbols being exported.

Comment: I've noticed that MinGW does that by default, which has caused confusion for me in the past, so thanks for clearing that up. Do you happen to know a way of forcing it to not do that?

Comment: @B3tturTh3nU:  it depends on the tool.  Tools which resemble MS options support a [linker `.def` (definitions) file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28d6s79h%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).  Borland supports this directly. But with `gcc`, it is almost certainly a command line option.